# Printing a matrix containing processes in C

Tags: c, matrix, printing, process, pid

I wrote a C program in which a 5x5 matrix generates a process by forking in each cell. The problem is that, if I try to print PIDs, it doesn't print the matrix correctly. Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 5
#define COL 5

int main (){

pid_t pid_matrix[ROW][COL];
  
for (size_t row = 0; row < ROW; ++row){
    for (size_t col = 0; col < COL; ++col){
        pid_matrix[row][col] = fork();
        if (pid_matrix[row][col] == -1){
            // Error! 
        }
        else if (pid_matrix[row][col] == 0){
            printf("\t%d", getpid());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
        } 
    }
    printf("\n");
}

    return 0;
}
```

Actually my code prints this:

```
    14233
    14234   14235   14236   14237   14238   14239   14240
    14241   14242   14243   14244   14245
    14246   14247   14248   14249   14250
    14251   14252   14253   14254
    14256   14255   14257
```

I tried to add a *sleep* after forking, but the result was this:

```
    14158   14159   14162   14163
    14164   14165   14166   14167   14168
    14169   14170   14171   14175   14176
    14177   14178   14179   14180   14181
    14182   14183   14184   14185   14186
    14187
```

Of course, my wanted code would print something like:

```
    14158   14159   14162   14163   14164
    14165   14166   14167   14168   14169
    14170   14171   14172   14173   14174
    14175   14176   14177   14178   14179
    14182   14183   14184   14185   14186
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to correct in my code to print the matrix correctly?

Comment: When you fork a processes, there is no guarantee (from a user-land perspective) what process the kernel will schedule next. Therefore, you cannot be certain that the parent process forks, hands execution to the child immediately, and have the kernel schedule execution for the parent again. You should use the wait system call to ensure that the parent blocks until the child exits, if you want to go down this route

Comment: `puts("\n")` will never be executed, since it's after `exit()`.

Comment: @Barmar I forgot to delete it, it was a trying.

Comment: The array is mostly irrelevant — you don't need it to get the information you're printing.  And it would be simpler to have the parent process print the matrix (whereupon it becomes relevant once more).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know. In my project I have to use a half-filled array with processes, so it was an exercise I did for myself to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `wait()` after processing loop body in parent process. This will assure that the child process has finished before processing another entry in the matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define ROW 5
#define COL 5

int main (){

pid_t pid_matrix[ROW][COL];
  
for (size_t row = 0; row < ROW; ++row){
    for (size_t col = 0; col < COL; ++col){
        pid_matrix[row][col] = fork();
        if (pid_matrix[row][col] == -1){
            // Error! 
        }
        else if (pid_matrix[row][col] == 0){
            printf("\t%d", getpid());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
        } 
        wait(NULL);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was simpler than I could imagine! Thanks a lot.